# How to change values in a dataframe to values from another dataframe, with closest match?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with real estate object parameters ('Rooms', 'Square' etc). I want to replace rows where 'Rooms' parameter equals to 0 to the corresponding number of rooms from a ('Rooms' - 'mean Square') dataframe I created from the same initial dataset.

I would use the .replace method, but the problem is - the actual Square values for 0 Room rows don't exactly match the mean values.

I'm new to pandas, so all solutions I would try are based on putting the column values into python lists and using cycles, which is a nightmare. All other similar topics I've seen on stackoverflow are good only for exact matches.

## This is the slice and part of the initial dataframe where I want the values ('Rooms') to be changed:

data.loc[data['Rooms'] == 0][['Rooms', 'Square']]

```
      Rooms Square
1397  0.0   138.427694
1981  0.0   212.932361
2269  0.0   41.790881
3911  0.0   49.483501
4366  0.0   81.491446
4853  0.0   2.377248
6149  0.0   38.697117
8834  0.0   87.762616
```

## This is the code that creates the 'Rooms' - 'mean Square' dataframe:

mean_square = data.loc[(data['Rooms'] < 6) & (data['Rooms'] > 0)].groupby('Rooms', as_index=False)['Square'].mean()

## This is the result:

```
    Rooms   Square
0   1.0     41.323277
1   2.0     56.788214
2   3.0     76.903234
3   4.0     98.377544
4   5.0     122.614941
```

For example, for item 1397 I would expect 0.0 changed to 5.0 (~138 sqm is closest to ~122 sq mean for 4 rooms).

Answer (score 2):

This is [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html). Taking your first slice as `df1` and the second as `df2`, we can find the nearest match, `'Rooms_y'`, and align the result on the original index.

```
import pandas as pd

df1['Rooms'] = (pd.merge_asof(df1.reset_index().sort_values('Square'), 
                              df2.sort_values('Square'), 
                              on='Square', direction='nearest')
                   .set_index('index')['Rooms_y']
                )
```

#### Output:

```
      Rooms      Square
1397    5.0  138.427694
1981    5.0  212.932361
2269    1.0   41.790881
3911    2.0   49.483501
4366    3.0   81.491446
4853    1.0    2.377248
6149    1.0   38.697117
8834    4.0   87.762616
```